# What are the (currently) known bugs in MVC 3 - preview 1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

As I just asked [a question on MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400949/in-mvc-one-edit-httppost-is-working-the-other-one-isnt-what-am-i-missing) (where I'm probably doing something wrong), I realized I may run across bugs or (soon-to-be-)known issues. This is currently Preview 1 of MVC 3, after all.

Is there already a set of known issues for MVC 3 Preview 1 (and if yes: what is it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is the [Issue Tracker](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/WorkItem/List.aspx) on MVC official site at CodePlex.

Answer (score 0):

Two more places:

- The [JsonValueProviderFactory issue, at Haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) and [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401071/what-are-the-currently-known-bugs-in-mvc-3-preview-1).
- [Scott Gu's own request to post your MVC 3 Bugs](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx) to [the ASP.NET MVC forum](http://forums.asp.net/1146.aspx).